# Tooltip mode doesn't seem work with custom HTML Tooltip

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I use a custom HTML tooltip.
But the mode doesn't seem to work. I want it to be 'point', but it looks like it uses 'index' when you use a custom HTML tooltip.

```
options: {
  tooltips: {
    enabled: false;
    mode: 'point',
    intersect: false,
    custom = //some code
  }
}
```

Is this a bug? Or it it supposed to work like this because it is a custom tooltip, and should I code myself a function to resize the right points on the chart?

And if it is supposed to be like this. What is the best approach to achieve this?

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api

Should I use beforeDatasetDraw in that case?